# Is it possible to write join down for Arrows, not ArrowApply?

Tags: haskell, monads, category-theory, arrows

I tried writing down `joinArr :: ??? a => a r (a r b) -> a r b`.
I came up with a solution which uses `app`, therefore narrowing the `a` down to `ArrowApply`'s:

```
joinArr :: ArrowApply a => a r (a r b) -> a r b
joinArr g = g &&& Control.Category.id >>> app
```

Is it possible to have this function written down for arrows?

My guess is no.

`Control.Monad.join` could have been a good stand-in for `>>=` in the definition of the `Monad` type class: `m >>= k = join $ k <$> m`.

Having `joinArr :: Arrow a => a r (a r b) (a r b)` on our hands, it would be possible to write down `instance Arrow a => Monad (ArrowMonad a)`:

```
m >>= k = joinArr (k <$> m)
```

*Please note that `joinArr` should be slightly tweaked to be able to deal with the wrapper. If we speak of `ArrowApply`:*

```
joinArr :: ArrowApply a => ArrowMonad a (ArrowMonad a b) -> ArrowMonad a b
joinArr (ArrowMonad m) = ArrowMonad $
   m &&& Control.Category.id >>>
   first (arr (\x -> let ArrowMonad h = x in h)) >>> 
   app
```

`instance ArrowApply a => Monad (ArrowMonad a)` is already implemented in the [source file](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/Control.Arrow.html#line-366).

I reckon this argument not to be the best one (if it is right).

Am I right? What is the more formal way to back this up (or disprove it)?

Comment: Hint: not every `Arrow` is a `Monad`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica true, that’s what I’m basing my argument on - we can be sure that an `Arrow` does not give rise to a `Monad` generally. Yet I reckon `joinArr :: Arrow a => a r (a r b) -> a r b` to enable us to write this down. Or am I using this fact wrongly?

Comment: If you had `joinArr`, then you could write `instance Monad SomeArrowThatIsntAMonad where m >>= f = joinArr (f <$> m)`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica yes, that was my point. At least I think so. How does it differ from my argument?

Comment: I think you're right. To make this formal, the only missing piece is a proof that there is some `Arrow` that doesn't admit a lawful `Monad` instance.

Comment: (1) Looking at it from another direction: between `(.)`, `id`, `arr` and `first`, there isn't anything that allows collapsing two `a r` layers into one. (2) @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica It's not a particularly enlightening example, perhaps, but [`Static`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-5.3.4/docs/Data-Semigroupoid-Static.html) for any applicative which isn't a monad should suffice. [`Scan`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.4.5/docs/Control-Scanl.html) from the *foldl* library might be a more interesting illustration.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I wish people stopped saying it like that. **No** arrow is a monad, they're abstractions on a fundamentally different approach. Many (not all) arrows _give rise_ to a monad, but it's missing the point to always discuss them only in that light. And probably a reason why arrows / cartesian monoidal categories haven't found much widespread applications yet; though the more important reason is certainly the fact that the unconstrained, mono-kinded, **Hask**-specific `Arrow` class as it stands doesn't really allow exploiting any of those beyond-monadish capabilities.

Answer (score 6):

I think the formal reason that you can’t implement `a x (a x y) -> a x y` using only `Arrow` is that this requires a notion of either application (as you tried) or currying, or rather uncurrying in this case:

```
uncurry :: a x (a y z) -> a (x, y) z
```

With that, `joinArr` is simply:

```
joinArr :: a x (a x y) -> a x y
joinArr f = dup >>> uncurry f
  where dup = id &&& id
```

But if we can’t implement this without `apply`, `curry`, or `uncurry`, that means that `a` must be a *Cartesian closed* category (CCC) because we need some notion of “exponential” or higher-order arrow, which `ArrowApply` gives us, but `Arrow` only gives us a *Cartesian* category. (And I believe `ArrowApply` is equivalent to `Monad` because `Monad` is a strong monad *in a CCC*.)

The closest you can get with only `Arrow` is an `Applicative`, as you saw in the definition of `instance (Arrow a) => Applicative (ArrowMonad a)`, which *happens* to be equivalent in power to `join` in the `Reader` monad (since there `join = (<*> id)`), but not the stronger monadic `join`:

```
joinArr' :: a x (x -> y) -> a x y
joinArr' f = (f &&& id) >>> arr (uncurry ($))
```

Note that instead of a higher-order arrow here, `a x (a x y)`, we just reuse the `(->)` type.

Comment: How can we be sure there's no other way to write `joinArr` down (without `app` or `uncurry`/`curry`)? Is this an observation or am I missing out on some theory?

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor: Because the type `a x (a x y)` is a “higher-order function”—that is, it has an `a` constructor *under* another `a`. This is using the strict definition of HoF, which includes *returning* functions (currying) in addition to accepting them as inputs, whereas in Haskell we informally call only the latter case a HoF, because we always have the option to uncurry `(->)`. The *minimal* structure needed to allow this is a category with embedded exponentials, which is precisely a CCC, which we spell `ArrowApply` or `Monad`. Not sure, but I think you could prove it by parametricity…