# How could sequence be written down for Arrows?

Tags: list, haskell, applicative, arrows, traversable

`sequenceA` is a well-known function:

```
sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
```

I wonder whether we can write down something similar for Arrows. Unfortunately, I did not manage to implement the following:

```
sequenceArr :: (Traversable t, Arrow a) => t (a b c) -> a b (t c)
```

As far as I understand, `Applicative` generalizes `Arrow`, thus, we should be able to write this down. I did it for lists:

```
sequenceArrLst :: Arrow a => [a b c] -> a b [c]
sequenceArrLst t = let t' = (>>> arr (: [])) <$> t
                   in foldr1 (\f g -> f &&& g >>> arr (uncurry (++))) t'
```

Yet as one can notice, we are not *getting rid of* the `a b` layer in the list but wrapping the results into a new list. So, how can we *actually* get rid of the `a b` layer? I should note that in the comments under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62542607/is-it-possible-to-write-join-down-for-arrows-not-arrowapply), [duplode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2751851/duplode) pointed out:

> ...between `(.)`, `id`, `arr` and `first`, there isn't anything that allows collapsing two `a r` layers into one.

If they are right, would we need `ArrowApply` for this? Frankly, I wrote this down, still not being able to get rid of the arrow inside `t`:

```
sequenceArrApp :: (Functor f, ArrowApply a) => f (a b c) -> a b (f (a () c))
sequenceArrApp t = arr $ \ b -> (\ f -> arr (\ () -> (f, b)) >>> app) <$> t
```

Could this snippet be tweaked to lack the `a ()` layer?

So, my questions are:

1. `sequenceArr :: (Traversable t, Arrow a) => t (a b c) -> a b (t c)` - can we write this down? If so, how?
2. Are there any ways to get rid of the `a b` layer (`Arrow a`). If so, why do they not work when we write [`join` for `Arrow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62542607/is-it-possible-to-write-join-down-for-arrows-not-arrowapply) down (if they actually do not)?
3. Do we need `ArrowApply` for this? If so, how? Could my variant be tweaked to get this result: `sequenceArr :: (Traversable t, ArrowApply a) => t (a b c) -> a b (t c)`?

Comment: I don't understand your complaint about the list version. Are you saying you really want something more like `traverseArr :: (Arrow a, Traversable t) => a x y -> a (t x) (t y)`? I think that would be a reasonable thing to try to get (whether possible or not, I don't know off the top of my head), but you haven't asked it directly.

Comment: The existence of the [`Traversing`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.5.2/docs/Data-Profunctor-Traversing.html) class suggests that `traverseArr` *likely* isn't available for arbitrary arrows.

Comment: @dfeuer yes. I added the direct question. I will look into the `Traversing` class as I have never heard of it before - thank you. What if we speak not an arbitrary arrow, but an `ArrowApply` instance? As far as I can remember, `sequence`s used to be fed lists only not so long ago, yet they got generalized. All I am trying to do is to keep up :).

Comment: Your `sequenceArr` likely *is* possible, with some hackery. See my implementation of [`traverseBia`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5.5.7/docs/Data-Biapplicative.html#v:traverseBia) for inspiration. Something like the sneaky [`Mag`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5.5.7/docs/src/Data.Biapplicative.html#Mag) `Applicative` might prove necessary.

Comment: Your `sequenceArr` looks quite different in shape from my `traverseArr`. Note that my `traverseArr` is much closer to what `traverse` (and `sequenceA`) do.

Comment: @dfeuer what type does suit `sequenceArr` more than?

Comment: The closest analogue would be `sa :: (Traversable t, _ a) => t (a () x) -> a () (t x)`, which feels very awkward!

Comment: @dfeuer I don't think `(Traversable t, _ a) => t (a () x) -> a () (t x)` is much of a problem. We have an instance `Arrow a => Applicative (ArrowMonad a)`, therefore `t (ArrowMonad a x) -> ArrowMonad a (t x)` is just `sequenceA` specialized to a wrapper (which, as far as I know, does not even exist in the runtime).

Comment: I don't think `sa` is likely to be very useful if you don't have `ArrowApply`.

Comment: Isn't the `sequenceArr` you propose at first what you get by specilaising `sequenceA` to the applicatives we can squeeze out of arrows? Or, in terms of [`WrappedArrow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:WrappedArrow), `unwrapArrow . sequenceA . fmap WrapArrow`?

Comment: @duplode to be frank, I am a bit clumsy with `Applicative` and have never heard of `WrappedArrow` (now I know it - thank you). Would you like to transfer your comment to the answers, so I can accept it?

Comment: @dfeuer do you mean that we need to have the `ArrowApply a` context? Well, this could be done the same way, I believe, as we have `ArrowApply a => Monad (ArrowMonad a)` and `sequence`. Did I get you right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I understand, `Applicative` generalizes `Arrow`, thus, we should be able to write this down.

Keeping in mind that "generalizes" here really means "if we pin down the input type argument of an `Arrow`, the resulting `* -> *` type constructor will be an `Applicative`", the `sequenceArr` you propose at first amounts to `sequenceA` specialised to the applicatives that can be squeezed from arrows in such a way. As those applicatives can be expressed through [the `WrappedArrow` newtype](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:WrappedArrow), one possible definition is:

```
sequenceArr :: (Traversable t, Arrow a) => t (a b c) -> a b (t c)
sequenceArr = unwrapArrow . sequenceA . fmap WrapArrow
```

Looking at how `WrappedArrow` instantiates `Applicative`...

```
instance Arrow a => Applicative (WrappedArrow a b) where
    pure x = WrapArrow (arr (const x))
    liftA2 f (WrapArrow u) (WrapArrow v) =
      WrapArrow (u &&& v >>> arr (uncurry f))
```

... should confirm this implementation agrees in spirit with your attempt at writing `sequenceArrLst`.

(Note this `sequenceArr` is indeed very different from [`traverse'`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.5.2/docs/Data-Profunctor-Traversing.html#v:traverse-39-) from `Data.Profunctors.Traversing` that dfeuer [discusses in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62762965/how-could-sequence-be-written-down-for-arrows?noredirect=1#comment110991125_62762965). Rather than being a specialization of `sequenceA`, `traverse'` generalizes `traverse` along, so to speak, a wholly other dimension.)